# Get value from table by button click (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have table in my view

Here is code

```
<tbody id="findings" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>

    <td style="display: none" id="patientId" class="title">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient_id)
    </td>
    <td class="title appdate">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Start_appointment)
    </td>
    <td id="nameVal" class="title">
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient.Name)
    </td>

    <td class="title">
      <img src="@item.Calculation.CalculationStatus" />
    </td>

    <td class="title">
      <img style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" class="open_calculation" src="~/images/icons8-Document-30.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  }
</tbody>
```

I need to get value from

```
<td class="title appdate">
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Start_appointment)
</td>
```

via button click `open_calculation`

How I can do this correctly via js?

Thank's for help.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, as you've tagged it, then you need these methods: [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click), [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find), [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text)

Comment: Like this `var date = $(this).find("tr").closest('.appdate').text();` ? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Yes, exactly like that - just make sure you execute that code in a `click` event handler.

Comment: That is not correct, if `this` is a `td. open_calculation` you'll need to use something like `$(this).parent("tr").find(".appdate").text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on("click", ".open_calculation", function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".appdate").text();
    });  
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Given the rows are generated in a loop this will get the text of *all* rows, not the clicked one

Comment: It will get it correctly?

Because I can have many entries in table?

Comment: @OldBalance Updated answer, hope this helps!

Comment: Seems it not getting text.

Comment: try .html() instead @OldBalance

Comment: Getting undefined

Comment: @OldBalance could you do a `console.log($(this).closest("tr").find(".appdate"))` and see if it prints something?

Comment: I find where was problem. I will post it as answer and mark you as right. Thank's so much.

Comment: I post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So according to @N.Ivanov answer I need to write code like this.

```
 $('.open_calculation').click(function() {
    openCalculation(this);
});
 function openCalculation(element) {
    $('#main_window').load('@Url.Action("OpenCalculationPartial", "Calculations")',
        function () {
           var date = "Finding from" + " " + $(element).closest("tr").find("#appdate").text().trim();
           $("#appointmentDate").text(date);
        });
}
```

Where was problem.

I use `this` in function,  but this context in function are different.

So code this code isn't right:

```
  $('.open_calculation').click(function() {
    openCalculation();
});
 function openCalculation(element) {
    $('#main_window').load('@Url.Action("OpenCalculationPartial", "Calculations")',
        function () {
           var date = "Finding from" + " " + $(element).closest("tr").find("#appdate").text().trim();
           $("#appointmentDate").text(date);
        });
}
```

Comment: You can just use `$('.open_calculation').click(openCalculation);` and `this` will be the clicked element.

Comment: Yeah. Thank's@Titus